# How to set this value as variable?

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I want to set the value of this part (shown in image[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdjDm.gif)) as a variable?

Comment: It's not clear what you question. If you question is "how to set some value into variable", then you should check some tutorial to this topic https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20assign%20a,value%20%22Volvo%22%20to%20it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put like `var myvariable = data.events`, and It should works, If you have any question just comment.

Comment: I mean, `data` is an object with children : events, births, and more.. i want to do like data.[STRING]

Comment: Just type `var myvariable = data`, and you can use everything in it,  `myvariable.`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways:

```js
const data = {event: 'some user event'};

// 1. dot notation
const userEvent1 = data.event;

// 2. Bracket Notation

const key = 'event'
const userEvent2 = data[key]; // or just data['event']

// 3. destructuring

const { event } = data;

console.log('userEvent1:', userEvent1)
console.log('userEvent2:', userEvent2)
console.log('event:', event)
```

I will attach useful articles:

https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781

https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do It With Pretty Much a lot of ways Like

But the Most Simplest Way is using dot notation
`const event = data.event`

Comment: Won't be technically a variable then. And besides, `const` excepted, that answer has already been given. Be sure when answering old questions with existing, upvoted, answers, to add new information that weren't given already in previous answers.